# Sound Processing - Beat Matching Music Player on Android

Tags: java, c++, android

So I want to make a new music player for Android, it's going to be open source and if you think this idea is any good feel free to let me know and maybe we can work on it.

I know it's possible to speed up and slow down a song and normalize the sound so that the voices and instruments still hit the same pitch.

I'd like to make a media play for Android aimed at joggers which will;

- Beat match successive songs
- Maintain a constant beat for running to
- Beat can be established via accelerometer or manually
- Alarms and notifications automatically at points in the run (Geo located or timer)

Now I know that this will fall down with many use cases (Slow songs sounding stupid, beat changes within song getting messed up) but I feel they can be overcome. What I really need to know is how to get started writing an application in C++ (Using the Android NDK) which will perform the analysis and adjust the stream.

Will it be feasible to do this on the fly? What approach would you use? A server that streams to the phone? Maybe offline analysis of the songs on a desktop that gets synched to your device via tether?

If this is too many questions for one post I am most interested in the easiest way of analysing the wave of an MP3 to find the beat. On top of that, how to perform the manipulation, to change the beat, would be my next point of interest.

I had a tiny crappy mp3 player that could do double speed on the fly so I'm sure it can be done!

Gav

Comment: Doing exact 2X speed playback (without raising the pitch) can be done much faster than arbitrary (e.g. 1.1032X or 0.92345X) shifted playback, which is why the crappy devices do it.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question but did you ever do this?  I am interested in seeing some code that would achieve this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technologically feasible on a smartphone-type device, although it is extremely difficult to achieve good-sounding pitch-shifting and time-stretching effects even on a powerful PC and not in realtime.

Pitch-shifting and time-stretching can be achieved on a relatively powerful mobile device in realtime (I've done it in .Net CF on a Samsung i760 smartphone) without overly taxing the processor (the simple version is not much more expensive than ordinary MP3 playback).  The effect is not great, although it doesn't sound too bad if the pitch and time changes are relatively small.

Automatic determination of a song's tempo might be too time-consuming to do in real time, but this part of the process could be performed in advance of playback, or it could be done on the next song well before the current song is finished playing.  I've never done this myself, so I dunno.

Everything else you mentioned is relatively easy to do.  However:  I don't know how easy Android's API is regarding audio output, or even whether it allows the low-level access to audio playback that this project would require.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you'll have 2 problems:

1. Finding the tempo of a song is not easy. The most common method involves autocorrolation, which involves quite a bit of calculus, so I hope you've studied up.
2. Actually changing the beat of a song without pitch shift is even harder, and still results in sound artifacts in the song. Typically it takes a long time to edit audio in this way, and it takes a lot of tinkering to get the song to sound good. To actually perform this in real time would be very, very hard. The actual process involves taking the Fourier Transform of the audio, shifting the frequency, and taking the inverse Fourier Transform. More calculus, this time with imaginary numbers.

If you really want to work on this I suggest taking a class in signals and systems from an Electrical Engineering department.

Perhaps an easier idea: Find the tempo of all the songs in a user's library, and just focus on playing songs with a close beat to the jogger's pace. You still need to do #1 but you don't need to worry about #2.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the audio speed on the fly is definetly doable; I'm not sure if it's doable on the G1.

Rather than writing your own source I would recommend looking at the MythTV source and/or the mplayer source code.  They both support speeding up video playback while compensating the audio.

Answer (score -2):

http://picard.exceed.hu/tcpmp/test/

tcpmp did all that you asked for on an iddy biddy Palm Centro... And More, Including Video! If it can be done on a Palm Centro, it sure as heck can be done on the Android!!